# Run FFT on data chunks to reduce peak memory usage

Tags: fft, radio

I am trying to run 'wsprd' on a micro-controller for reduced power consumption and fun.

'wsprd' is open-source at https://github.com/pavel-demin/wsprd.

This program currently processes ~15 seconds of audio data in one go leading to a peak memory usage of around 21 MB.

We would like to bring this memory usage under 8 MB (limit of common PSRAM chips).

After profiling the wsprd code with 'valgrind --tool=massif', we found that the following code section is amenable to optimizations.

From https://github.com/pavel-demin/wsprd/blob/master/wsprd.c,

```
unsigned long readwavfile(char * ptr_to_infile, int ntrmin, float * idat, float * qdat) {
    size_t i, j, npoints;
    int nfft1, nfft2, nh2, i0;
    double df;

    nfft2 = 46080; //this is the number of downsampled points that will be returned
    nh2 = nfft2 / 2;

    nfft1 = nfft2 * 32; //need to downsample by a factor of 32
    npoints = 114 * 12000;

    float * realin;
    float * fftin, * fftout;
    PFFFT_Setup * fftsetup1, * fftsetup2;

    FILE * fp;
    short int * buf2;

    fp = fopen(ptr_to_infile, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open data file '%s'\n", ptr_to_infile);
        return 1;
    }

    buf2 = calloc(npoints, sizeof(short int));
    fread(buf2, 2, 22, fp); //Read and ignore header
    fread(buf2, 2, npoints, fp); //Read raw data
    fclose(fp);

    realin = pffft_aligned_malloc(sizeof(float) * nfft1);
    fftout = pffft_aligned_malloc(sizeof(float) * 2 * (nfft1 / 2 + 1));
    fftsetup1 = pffft_new_setup(nfft1, PFFFT_REAL);

    for (i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
        realin[i] = buf2[i] / 32768.0;
    }

    for (i = npoints; i < (size_t) nfft1; i++) {
        realin[i] = 0.0;
    }

    free(buf2);

    pffft_transform_ordered(fftsetup1, realin, fftout, NULL, PFFFT_FORWARD);
    pffft_aligned_free(realin);
    ...
}
```

Instead of processing all of the data (of length `nfft1`) in one go, is it
possible to process data in chunks (of size `nfft2` perhaps)?

A naive attempt (without understanding how the underlying function works and accesses data) at doing so didn't work out (the underlying program functionality broke completely).

```
for (int index = 0; index < 32; index++) {
    fftsetup1 = pffft_new_setup(nfft2, PFFFT_REAL);
    pffft_transform_ordered(fftsetup1, realin + (index * nfft2), fftout + (index * nfft2), NULL, PFFFT_FORWARD);
};
```

It would be great to get some help on this topic. Thank you!